# traversing numbers in an interval wisely

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, search, counting

I want to scan the numbers in a big interval wisely until I find the one I need.
But, I don't have any clue where this number might be and I will not have any clue during searching process.

Let me give an example to make it easy to state my question

Assume I am searching a number between 100000000000000 and 999999999999999

Naive approach would be starting from 100000000000000 and counting to 99... one by one.
but this is not wise because number can be on the far end If I am not lucky.

so, what is the best approach to this problem. I am not looking for mathematically best, I need a technique which is easy to implement in C programming Language.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know if you have found the one you need? Are you searching all numbers in the range, or just some? And if just some, are they sorted?

Comment: I am looking for one of the possibly few numbers. I have a tester function for solving PCP problem by brutforce method, that's why they cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution to your problem, but knowledge. If you don't know anything about the number, any strategy to enumerate them is equally good (or bad).

If you suppose that you are fighting against an adversary that is trying to hide the number for you, a strategy would be to make your next move unguessable. That would be to randomly pick numbers in the range and ask for them. (to avoid repetitions, you'd have to use a random permutation of your numbers.) By that you'd then find your number with an expected number of about half the total number, that is you'd gain a factor of two from the worst case. But as said all of that depends on the assumption that you can make.

Comment: yes it is true, there is no solution to this problem at all. But, I said, I am looking for best approach which doesn't have to be a proper solution necessarily.

for example, if one starts counting from min number of interval to max of it, it is not a better approach than counting from min to max and max to min simultaneously or dividing interval to small pieces and seek the number each of them again simultaneously by making use of multithreading.

Comment: As Jens said, any strategy is equally good/bad. Multithreading doesn't help unless you have multiple processors -- if you do you can obviously break he problem into n smaller problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use bisection search. First see if your number is above or below the middle of the range. Depending on the answer, repeat the process for the upper or lower half of the range, respectively.

Comment: but the problem is there is no way to determine if it is below of the range.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know there is no strategy to improve search speed. All you can do is to speed up the search itself by using multithreading. So the technically best approach might be to try to implement the algorithm in [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) (which is fairly similar to C and which can be used through a C library) and run several hundred tests in parallel, depending on your hardware (GPU).